# searching alphanumeric string

Tags: php, mysql, query-string, alphanumeric

I have a varchar field in mysql table and I want to search string in php which is alphanumeric
right now it shows number only results.

For example if I search for **111** then it should show results matching **111( 111A, 111B, 111C)**. If I search for **111A** then it should show results of **111A**.
How to achieve this.

Comment: where column like '%111%'

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your case is to the contrary of what **LIKE** does. It appears like you already use LIKE, and should not be using it for any exact match. Query may look like

```
SELECT myField from MyTable where myValue = '111'
SELECT myField from MyTable where myValue = '111A'
```

**To achieve the opposite**

You can use **LIKE**

```
SELECT myField from MyTable where myValue LIKE '111%'
```

This is for strings like 111Anything

```
SELECT myField from MyTable where myValue LIKE '%111%'
```

This is for strings like Anything111Anything

```
SELECT myField from MyTable where myValue LIKE '%111'
```

This is for strings like Anything111

Comment: Thanks . ( SELECT myField from MyTable where myValue = '111') worked .

Answer (score 1):

Search patterns in php:
from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

```
<?php
$subject = array("111A", "111B", "222");
$pattern = "/^111/";
$matches = preg_grep($pattern, $subject);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `LIKE` you can use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

For **Start with 111**

```
SELECT myField from MyTable where myValue REGEXP `^111`;
```

For **End with 111**

```
SELECT myField from MyTable where myValue REGEXP `111$`;
```

For **Start with 111 and End with 111**

```
SELECT myField from MyTable where myValue REGEXP `^111$`;
```